# Named callback function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to use callback functions in a JS file for phonegap.
The plugin I want to use is this: [documentation](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) .

The following syntax is given:

`bluetoothle.initialize(successFunction, errorFunction, parameter)`

I understand that `successFunction` is the function called whene `initialize` has succeeded. So I tried two ways.
This one works:

```
bluetoothle.initialize(function()
                    {
                        document.getElementById("testvalue").value += "\ninitialized";
                    }, function(){}, {"request": true, "statusReceiver": false});
```

And this doesn't:

```
var event = 
{
    onInitialized: function()
                    {
                        document.getElementById("testvalue").value += "\ninitialized";
                    },                      
    onError: function(message)
                {
                    document.getElementById("testvalue").value += "\nError: " + message;
                }
};
bluetoothle.initialize(event.onInitialized, event.onError, {"request": true, "statusReceiver": false});
```

I guess all I changed is naming the callback function. What is wrong here?

Comment: What error message are you getting?  The code you posted should probably work, unless the mistake is using the `message` parameter.

Comment: My guess is event is probably already being used as a variable name. Try something like `var myCustomEvent = ....`

Comment: I upload my code to Adobe PhoneGap Build and install the app on a smartphone. Because of this I don't get any error message. Just nothing happens whene the code is executed. It seems like the callback doesn't work. No the `message` parameter is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an inconsistency with the [plugin code](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle/blob/master/www/bluetoothle.js):

```
var bluetoothle = {
  initialize: function(successCallback, params) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback, successCallback, bluetoothleName, "initialize", [params]);
  },
```

I'm only seeing one param here. I suggest you try an earlier version

Comment: @timdelawe - glad to hear it. You might consider linking to this issue on the plugins github page.